# How to relate two arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

What is typically the process of creating arrays that relate to each other?

What I'm trying to do is to create a simple-shopping-list app where I will have two arrays, `stores` and `items` which will be displayed in a UITableView. The `stores` arrays will be displayed in the main tableView and the `items` array will be displayed in a detail tableView when an item from the `stores` array is tapped, but I'm not sure how this is typically done, I'm assuming I need some sort of two dimensional array (or one-to-many array) but I'm a little confused.

Here is the code I have which displays the `stores` array in the main tableView.

Store Class:

```
import Foundation

class Store{
    var storeName = ""
}
```

Item Class:

```
import Foundation

class Item : Object{
    var itemName: String = ""
    var price: Double = 0
}
```

Main ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var storesTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputStoreName: UITextField!

    var itemList = [Item]() // I'm not sure how to use this array
    var storeList = [Store]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       storesTable.dataSource = self
       storesTable.delegate = self
    }
    @IBAction func addNewStore() {
        let store =  Store()
        store.storeName =  inputStoreName.text!
        storeList.append(store)
        storesTable.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storeList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell")! as UITableViewCell
        let data  =  storeList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data.storeName)"
        return cell
    }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "detailTableView"{
      if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailTableViewController{

          let selectedStore = storeList[(storesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!].storeName
        destination.messageFromMainController = selectedStore
      }
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: I only have a superficial understanding of what you're trying to do, but this sounds like a job for a `Map`, where the elements of `stores` are the keys, and lists of `items` are the values.

Comment: you can try [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) or core data. Using Realm as an example, you can have a store object with a list of items. They have an example using dogs and owner relationship you can check out.

Comment: @JustinM That is ultimately my goal, I will be using Realm,  but I thought this would be a simpler step to have a better understanding, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to make changes in your model classes:

Store Class:

```
class Store{
    var storeName = ""
    var itemList : Array<Item>? = []
}
```

Now when you add the new store, you will add the items of this store with name.

```
 @IBAction func addNewStore() {
            let store =  Store()
            let item1 = Item()
            item1.itemName = "FirstStoreFirstItem"
            item1.price = "100"
            let item2 = Item()
            item2.itemName = "FirstStoreSecondtItem"
            item2.price = "200"
            store.storeName =  inputStoreName.text!
            store.itemList.append(item1)
            store.itemList.append(item2)
            storeList.append(store)
            storesTable.reloadData()
        }
```

Now when you select any store then you will get the details of items in that store as below

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "detailTableView"{
      if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailTableViewController{

          let selectedStore = storeList[(storesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
         print(selectedStore.storeName)
         print(selectedStore.itemList[0].itemName)
         print(selectedStore.itemList[0].price)
        destination.messageFromMainController = selectedStore
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: It worked, the only thing I had to change was the array declaration in the `Store` class to `var itemList = [Item]()`  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add items in Store model

```
class Store{
var storeName = ""
var items:[Item]? = nil
}
```

Initiate Store object along with items.

Comment: by default optionals are `nil`. so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: Yea...not necessary to add that.

Comment: @user3608500 Thanks a lot!